# properties of largest eignvalue of product of two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm searching for the proof of this lemma
it's about largest eignvalue of product of two matrices. one of them is positive definete and the other one is symmetric.
B is symmetric matrix, A is Positive definite. Then :  x'Bx =< landamax(inv(A)B).x'Ax

Comment: What is the lemma????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $B$ is symmetric and $A$ positive definite, let $C = A^{-1/2} B A^{-1/2}$.
Then $C$ has the same eigenvalues as $A^{-1} B$.  Moreover, for any $x$, 
if $y = A^{1/2} x$ we have $x' A x = y' y$ and
$x' B x = y' C y$.  If $\lambda_\max$ is the largest eigenvalue of $C$, then
$y' C y \le \lambda_\max \; y' y$.  Put it all together and you have
$x' B x \le \lambda_\max x' A x$.